# How to apply formatting to StringBuilder output in a C# WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a Windows Form application that displays the results of a SQL query. I'd like to allow my user to save a copy of the generated report to a Word document, and I'm using a StringBuilder method to build my output file.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to apply rich text formatting (font, bold, tables, etc) and writing something like this:

```
sb.AppendLine("<b>" + "This is my text." + "</b>");
```

as I would do in ASP.NET produces this output: "`<b>This is my text.</b>`".

This means that all I can produce now is an ugly text file with no formatting whatsoever. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That completely depends on the file format that you're writing.

Comment: What doesn't work with that approach? Or do you just not know how to write a word document (no interop?)?

Comment: @SLaks I've tried saving my file to ".doc" format using this approach, and got the results mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using the [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) library to generate and format Word documents from C# code.

Comment: This seems to be working. Thanks for letting me know about this.